# Search Algorithm for Linked List in C

Tags: c, algorithm, search

I have just started a school project, and that project I need to use Linked List. Also, I need search some data inside of Linked List.

I have been doing some research on search algorithms.
I looked at :

`Binary Search` (recursive one) - looks hard to implements-

`Sequential Search` - complexity already O(N)

`Exponential Search` -based on Binary Search-

Which algorithm can I use in the most efficient way? Also, the search algorithm complexity must be lower than **O(N)**. I am open for any suggestion

Details of my Assignments:
They want us to write basic facebook on a console. it will do Add friend, block friend, liked that stuff.

There will linked list and contains name, surname, gender and date of birth. Moreover, these data will comes from **File**. Before you load the data to linked list, it will be sorted, then will load to linked list.

Assignments have 5 backbone functions : **Insert** (basically add people to linked list and sort it), **search** (search the specific person and says complexity must be O(logN), **Print**, **Block people** and print **blocked person**,

EDIT:
I think It is kind of Binary Search:

I call the binary search as `searchFriends(FList, 0, FList->size - 1);`

Inside of the searchFriends:

```
void searchFriends(List FList, int l, int r)
{
    if (r - 1 >= 1)
    {
        int middleItem = l + (r - 1) / 2;
        struct Node* temp = FList->head->next;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < middleItem)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            i++;
        }
        if (strcmp(temp->Name, "Name") == 0)
        {
            printf("\nName\t\tSurname\t\tGender\t\tBirth Year\n");
            printf("%-15s %-15s %-15c %s\n", temp->Name, temp->Surname, temp->Gender, temp->DateofBirth);
        }
        if (strcmp(temp->Name, "Name") > 0)
            return searchFriends(FList, l, middleItem - 1);

        return searchFriends(FList, middleItem + 1, r);
}
```

}

Comment: I think binary and exponential search would not work as they both need sorted array and in linked list you cannot access a element by its index .

Comment: So linear search / sequencial search looks to be the best option.

Comment: Most people do linear search on linkedlist. It would be easiest to implement as all you do is a simple while loop until the next is not null....

Comment: @pulankit Yeah, I tried to implement but it does not work, or I could not do it. Other than these three, do you have another opinion ?

Comment: In linked list traversing is the only option you have, so i think you only have one option linear search, btw its very easy to implement though could u share your peace of code which didnt work.

Comment: It depends on what your goal is, and what the linkedlist is for. Most people who use LinkedList are not looking for efficiency but used for a data structure with simple structure and easy adding/deleting, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is a lower than O(N) solution possible, unless it is sorted. Even logically speaking you have to "see" all elements in the list once in the worst case.

Comment: @OmidCompSCI I am taking data structure course on C, it is easy to delete or add on.

Comment: Hi, you can try using more than one pointer which will look at two node at a time. Which might reduce traversal by half.

Comment: @pulankit I actually did, I implemented kind of Binary Seach. I will update post

Comment: That there’s an O(n²) binary search. You are playing with an interesting trade-off: effort taken to compare an element with the search term, and effort taken to traverse nodes. No matter what, this algorithm searches from the first node on each iteration. Better to add arguments to access individual nodes in addition to numeric indices — you might get O(nlogn), which is still worse than O(n). (You also have hard-coded the search term to be "Name". Make the name to find an argument.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep in mind that a standard linked list is **not** random access. The only way to traverse such a list is linear.

Hence, it is not possible to use random-access algorithms like binary search on a linked list. You must do a sequential == linear search, and your worst-case complexity is O(n).

Comment: All of you are right, but they want us to write O(logN) complexity search algorithm. I will look at it more. Probably they want us to use some kind of dive and conquer algorithms

Comment: I don’t understand how they expect you to do an O(logn) algorithm on an O(n) structure. Is this really a skip-list or something?

Comment: I do not have any idea, If you want,  I can send the question

Comment: Post details of the assignment in your question.

Comment: Well, your assignment is, unfortunately, non-sequitur. You are being asked to use a linked list, but search with a random-access complexity. I recommend sending an email to your professor asking for clarification.